# Flow runs successfully for Community user only when "Show details of what's executed and render flow in Lightning runtime" deselected

Tags: visual-workflow, debugging, insufficient-privileges, digital-experience

I have a flow that is to be used on a community. When debugging the flow fails for the community user when "Show details of what's executed and render flow in Lightning runtime" is selected as shown below [image]

The error message received is "(The flow tried to update these records: null. This error occurred: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY: insufficient access rights on object id.)."

However when the checkbox is not selected, the flow runs fine for the user. Any help with resolving the issue highly appreciated as for the moment the flow fails when published on Experience.

Comment: Are multi-select picklists involved here? Looks related to [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001RXO4QAO)

Comment: No multi select picklists involved.